# Updating data from remote server in android webview

Tags: android, eclipse, html, android-webview, automatic-updates

I have an app which uses android webview for the local html files stored in assets folder.
I was wondering if it is possible to update the local html file without updating the app

Answer (score 0):

You have to take little different approach to do this. If you keep html file in your asset folder you can't update it. What I have done is I placed the html file in database folder where you can update it programmatically.

**Step 1.** You cannot place the file while building the app, you can download the html file in a zip format when the app is launched and extract it in database folder.

**Step 2.** To update the file just download update zip file from the server and replace with the existing file same as Step 1.

Hope this helps. I have done the same for my project and it's working like a charm.

Comment: Can u give example because I have no idea how to do it plus I don't know much about it @Amitabh